# Конкатенацию ряда чисел

Tags: c++

Я новичок так что особо не бейте.

Как в плюсах сделать конкатенацию ряда чисел получаемого из некоего источника?
Например пусть будет из цикла `for` по 1 однозначному числу за итерацию.

```
srand(time(0));
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    cout << rand() % 9;
}
```

В результате собранное число должно находится в обычной переменной типа `int`.

Какие существуют варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В 10ичной системе счисления основание 10, надо умножать, имеющееся число, на это основание и только затем прибавлять новую цифру.

```
srand(time(0));
int num = 0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    num *= 10;
    num += rand() % 9;
}
cout << num << endl;
```

> - 0
> - 0 -> 0*10 -> 0 + rand()%9 { допустим 8 }
> - 8 -> 8*10 -> 80 + rand()%9 { допустим 7 }
> - 87 -> 87*10 -> 870 + rand()%9

P.S. Автор в комментариях просит сравнение результатов

```
srand(0);
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    cout << rand() % 9;
}
cout << endl;

srand(0);
int num = 0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    num *= 10;
    num += rand() % 9;
}
cout << num << endl;
```

Comment: Что то не получается:
Если допустим использовать Ваш код без srand

int num = 0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    num *= 10;
    num += rand() % 9;
}
cout << "\n" << num << endl;

Второе число это Ваше
58748130
72827675

Comment: не понял, в чём ошибка? В том что они разные?

Comment: ну да, без srand они же должны быть одинаковые

Comment: а вы две программы отдельно запускаете? Или последовательно код поставили?

Comment: последовательно, можно и отдельно, результат один будет
но суть я понял, но код почему то не работает

Comment: если последовательно, то надо rand сбрасывать, так как счётчик каждый раз на rand изменяется. Напишите `srand(0)` перед каждым циклом, тогда будет одинаковая последовательность

Comment: Дописал код, чтобы было понятно

Comment: Спасибо Андрей, заработало!!!

А еще вопросик, как так же в двоичной системе счисления?
На 2 умножать просто?

Comment: вообще да, но там с выводом на экран могут быть трудности, если вам просто нужно вывести число из 1 и 0 и вы не хотите париться, то можно также на 10 домножать, просто `rand()%2` должно быть в таком случае. Есть и другой способ, если работать именно с двоичной системой, можно с помощью битового сдвига (оператор `<<`, по сути эквивалент умножения на 2) все единицы и нули сдвигать.